# chrome app notifications doesnt show a baloon notif

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-app

I'm currently studying how to use chrome app notification api.

```
var options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Your Title",
    message: "Your message"
}
chrome.notifications.create("notificationName", options, function(){
    console.log('Notification Created!');
});
```

What I'm expecting with this code is to create a notification then log a message into the console and show baloon notif in notifications panel. But the result is it only logs the message and the baloon notif didnt appear. Please help me.

**Note:** I,m using windows 8 and google chrome version 36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing [required properties](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions).

You can examine `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback to know more, but off the top of my head, for the `type: "basic"` you require a valid `iconUrl`.